# Mongoose store Date without Time

Tags: date, mongoose

I need to store my Date in mongoose without time
This is how i defined in mongoose model schema

```
created_at : {type: Date, default: Date.now}
```

While am using this, am getting date with time. How can i store only date in mongoose without time

Comment: [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) is a javascript built in object which you can do lots of stuff with, like only getting date by [`toDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) method.

Comment: am getting date from database

Answer (score 0):

I did like this :

```
 let lv_today_string = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
 let lv_today_date = new Date(lv_today_string)
```

and set this lv_today_date  variable to Mongo :

```
created_at: lv_today_date
```